# How to change tab using props for material ui tabs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Looking at this example: [Link to Material UI Tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/)

If I have a these tabs components in a widget, and if I want to have an image or icon, how would I be able to link the icon or image so that on click it would change to the tab I want it to change to? And I am not using react-router or anything.

Any directions to this would be helpful, whether to be passing a prop or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs has a `value` property , that indicates whether a tab has to be open or not:

```
 <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
```

You need to add this `handleChange` method to the icon or image that you want to use as a `button`.

Maybe add some code to see if is that simple or you need to pass your `method` to other `component`.

Comment: @AsifKabani If this helped you please accept the answer, in order to close this question as resolved